# Pandas column value pass or fail based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```py
df_house = 
    house_id    test    result
0   House1  door    Pass
1   House1  window  Pass
2   House1  roof    Pass
3   House2  door    Pass
4   House2  window  fail
5   House2  roof    pass
```

and I want to create a summary df:

```py
df_summary = 
    house_id    test_summary
0   House1  Pass
1   House2  Fail
```

- How can i do this in Pandas?
- Note that the result is Pass if all the tests were Pass and it's not case-sensitive so any value of pass,Pass,PASS,etc should be counted as pass.

ANSWER:

```
df_house['result'].str.lower().eq('pass').groupby(df_house['house_id']).all().map({True:'Pass',False:'Fail'}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `groupby` with `all`

```
df = df['result'].eq('Pass').groupby(df['house_id']).all().map({True:'Pass',False : 'fail'}).reset_index()
Out[117]: 
  house_id result
0   House1   Pass
1   House2   fail
```

Comment: Based on the input, there's an issue with `.eq('Pass')` because the last row is `pass` not `Pass`.  Probably needs `.str.lower().eq('pass')`

Comment: thanks. i added .str.lower() to make is work with any case: